# The problem of not installing application on google play

Tags: android, google-play, package

When I uploaded it to google play, I got a `com.example` error, and then I typed another name instead of example and fixed all the places. I also corrected the package name in the google service json file. But it does not receive an error but when I run the application I get a `"myappname" is stopped` error. I have no idea what the problem is. What could it be? Where did the missing or wrong?

places where I make correction;

1. package names in all activity and fragments
2. googleservice.json file
3. package name in manifest

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update in your `build.gradle` file like this

```
android {
        applicationId "your.new.domain"
    }
```

And then, Sync the project.

Comment: I forgot to write, I do it. Mainactivity unresolved error in manifest file @Félix Maroy

Comment: Can I see the structure of your Project ? (screenshot)